# Is there are solution to get elements with different names into my XSL result?

Tags: xml, xslt

i want to get the Property Elements into my result.
I could not figure out how to select it.
I want to have 3 additional Elements in my :

```
<Hangings>0</Hangings>
<Confirmed>1</Confirmed>
<InvoiceNo>48038-01a</InvoiceNo>
```

Desired Output XML:

```
<Headers>
 <Header>
  <SupplierPartyID>289</SupplierPartyID>
  <SupplierPartyName>XYZ</SupplierPartyName>
  <SupplierPartyLocationName>INDIA</SupplierPartyLocationName>
  <Hangings>0</Hangings>
  <Confirmed>1</Confirmed>
  <InvoiceNo>48038-01a</InvoiceNo>
 </Header>
</Headers>
```

I was trying for hours to get the solution. But unfortunately without success.
Any hint on how to do that?

XML looks like that:

```
<ProcessReceiveDelivery xmlns="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9"
                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                        releaseID="1"
                        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9 ProcessReceiveDelivery.xsd"
                        systemEnvironmentCode="Test">
   <ApplicationArea>
      <CreationDateTime>2019-03-28T07:35:24.615</CreationDateTime>
   </ApplicationArea>
   <DataArea>
      <Process/>
      <ReceiveDelivery>
         <ReceiveDeliveryHeader>
            <SupplierParty>
               <PartyIDs>
                  <ID>289</ID>
               </PartyIDs>
               <Name>XYZ</Name>
               <Location>
                  <Name>INDIA</Name>
               </Location>
            </SupplierParty>
            <UserArea>
               <Property>
                  <NameValue name="Hangings">0</NameValue>
               </Property>
               <Property>
                  <NameValue name="Confirmed">1</NameValue>
               </Property>
               <Property>
                  <NameValue name="InvoiceNo">48038-01a</NameValue>
               </Property>
            </UserArea>
         </ReceiveDeliveryHeader>
```

XSL looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:met="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9"
                exclude-result-prefixes="met">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"
                encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="met:ProcessReceiveDelivery">
    <Headers>
<xsl:for-each select="met:DataArea/met:ReceiveDelivery/met:ReceiveDeliveryHeader">
        <Header>
            <SupplierPartyID><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(met:SupplierParty/met:PartyIDs)"/></SupplierPartyID>
            <SupplierPartyName><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(met:SupplierParty/met:Name)"/></SupplierPartyName>
            <SupplierPartyLocationName><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(met:SupplierParty/met:Location/met:Name)"/></SupplierPartyLocationName>
        </Header>
</xsl:for-each>
    </Headers>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please add **desired output** XML to the question.

Comment: Thank you. I added the desired output XML.

Comment: Your input XML is cut off in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:met="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9"
exclude-result-prefixes="met">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/met:ProcessReceiveDelivery">
    <Headers>
        <xsl:for-each select="met:DataArea/met:ReceiveDelivery/met:ReceiveDeliveryHeader">
            <Header>
                <!-- Supplier Party -->
                <SupplierPartyID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(met:SupplierParty/met:PartyIDs)"/>
                </SupplierPartyID>
                <SupplierPartyName>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(met:SupplierParty/met:Name)"/>
                </SupplierPartyName>
                <SupplierPartyLocationName>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(met:SupplierParty/met:Location/met:Name)"/>
                </SupplierPartyLocationName>
                <!-- User Area -->
                <Hangings>
                    <xsl:value-of select="met:UserArea/met:Property/met:NameValue[@name='Hangings']"/>
                </Hangings>
                <Confirmed>
                    <xsl:value-of select="met:UserArea/met:Property/met:NameValue[@name='Confirmed']"/>
                </Confirmed>
                <InvoiceNo>
                    <xsl:value-of select="met:UserArea/met:Property/met:NameValue[@name='InvoiceNo']"/>
                </InvoiceNo>
            </Header>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Headers>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Not sure why you need the `normalize-space()`; there isn't any redundant white space in the provided input example.

Comment: Good point. When I do not use it, I get spaces in front of the values. I was also confused because there are no spaces in the input file.

Comment: Ah, I now see why. It's because you're selecting the parent of the leaf element instead of the element itself. You have: `<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(met:SupplierParty/met:PartyIDs)"/>`, you should have `<xsl:value-of select="met:SupplierParty/met:PartyIDs/met:ID"/>`.

Comment: Well, that works, I corrected both! Thank you! Is there also a way to get access to ApplicationArea/CreationDateTime?

Comment: You can use `<xsl:value-of select="met: ApplicationArea/met: CreationDateTime"/>` outside the `xsl:for-each` instruction,  or `<xsl:value-of select="/met:ProcessReceiveDelivery/met: ApplicationArea/met: CreationDateTime"/>` from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Or do it using templates like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:met="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9"
  exclude-result-prefixes="met">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"
    encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="met:ProcessReceiveDelivery">
    <Headers>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="met:DataArea/met:ReceiveDelivery/met:ReceiveDeliveryHeader"/>
    </Headers>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="met:ReceiveDelivery">
    <Header>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="met:DataArea/met:ReceiveDelivery"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="met:DataArea/met:UserArea/met:Property/met:NameValue"/>
    </Header>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="met:SupplierParty">
    <SupplierPartyID><xsl:value-of select="met:PartyIDs/met:ID"/></SupplierPartyID>
    <SupplierPartyName><xsl:value-of select="met:Name"/></SupplierPartyName>
    <SupplierPartyLocationName><xsl:value-of select="met:Location/met:Name"/></SupplierPartyLocationName>
  </xsl:template>
      
  <xsl:template match="met:NameValue">
    <xsl:element name="{@name}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```